# Using array in where clause in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$order_mealsInfo_ids` which has the values like this

`[{"meal_id":"33"},{"meal_id":"34"}]`

Both the `meal_id` "33" and "34" has the same values(store_name,franchise_id,order_datetime) so I only want to get those values once that's why I am using distinct keyword.I want to use `$order_mealsInfo_ids` in my query,My query is :

```
    $get_franchise_info="Select distinct store_name,franchise_id,order_datetime from order_main where id 
IN (".implode(',',$order_mealsInfo_ids['meal_id']).")";
```

But its giving this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: meal_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\service\get_pending_orders_news.php on line 94
>
> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\service\get_pending_orders_news.php on line 94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[{"meal_id":"33"},{"meal_id":"34"}]**  this is not **Array** this is **json**

you need to convert **json to array**

```
`$array = json_decode($json);
$mapedarray = array_map('current',$array);
$data = implode(',',$mapedarray);
echo $data;
`
```

so you get 33,34

```
`
 $get_franchise_info="Select distinct store_name,franchise_id,order_datetime from order_main where id 
IN (".implode(',',$mapedarray).")";
`
```

or

```
 `
     $get_franchise_info="Select distinct store_name,franchise_id,order_datetime from order_main where id 
    IN (".$data.")";
    `
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case `$order_mealsInfo_ids` is not an PHP array. It's a string containing a JSON array.

Please try this:

```
$order_mealsInfoJSON = '[{"meal_id":"33"},{"meal_id":"34"}]';
$order_mealsInfoArr = json_decode($order_mealsInfoJSON); // Convert JSON string to PHP array containing objects.

$order_mealsInfoIds = array();
foreach($order_mealsInfoArr as $order_mealsInfo) {
    $order_mealsInfoIds[] = $order_mealsInfo->meal_id;
}

$get_franchise_info="Select distinct store_name,franchise_id,order_datetime from order_main where id IN (".implode(',', $order_mealsInfoIds).")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    $data_jsn = '[{"meal_id":"33"},{"meal_id":"34"}]';
    $data = json_decode($data_jsn,true);
    $data_val = array_map(function($element) {
      return $element['meal_id'];
    }, $data);

    $get_franchise_info="Select distinct store_name,franchise_id,order_datetime from order_main where id 
    IN (".implode(',',$data_val).")";
```